# Как переименовывать файл, если он подвергается изменению через сигнал или метод save? Django

Tags: python, django

Когда я загружаю файл(изображение), я создаю вторую версию этого файла, только с другим разрешением(ширина х высота). Как мне добавлять к имеющемуся имени файла строку "Size Cover", если я определяю файл как self.image или instance.image?
Предположим, что это сигнал или метод save:

```
def image_post_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.banners:
        preview_cover = Image.open(instance.image)
        extension = imghdr.what(instance.image.path)
        cover_size = (200, 350)
        preview_cover.thumbnail(cover_size)
        preview_cover.save(instance.image.path)
''' И где то здесь перед preview_cover save должно 
    происходить переименовывание файла
    посредством добавления строки COVER_RESIZED'''
```

Comment: А что функции save на вход подается ? небось имя файла. так поправьте это самое имя пред тем как вызвать save

Comment: В save у меня нет упоминания поле image

Comment: Откуда берётся instance.image.path

Comment: Ну по идее instance это типо замена self в методе save. Я точно не знаю, писал сигнал следуя по видео, только для изменения разрешения

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич

Comment: preview_cover.save(f'{instance.image.path}-resized') - например так?

Comment: @Михаил Алексеевич Спасибо, попробую завтра уже. Сейчас просто спать лег уже